# Is there a program/shell where I can practice javascript?

Tags: javascript, shell, compiler-construction

I am beginner and I am teaching myself JavaScript with online tutorials. I can online type in what the tutorial asks me to type in for practice. However I want to be able to practice on my own, is there a website I can write in or a program I can download to practice.

I can program in Python but I know javascript is different in how compile.

Comment: On Chrome, hit Ctrl-Shift-J. On Firefox, Ctrl-Shift-K (or with Firebug, F12 then select the Console tab). On Opera, Ctrl-Shift-I then select Console. On IE, F12 then select Console.

Comment: It's called a "browser", and you obviously used one already to enter this question. Pretty much all recent/major browsers have a development/debug environment built into them.

Comment: @user2357112 http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ It works for justa about all of the web technologies, javascript, jquery, angular, knockout, etc

Comment: One does not simply *compile* JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [built in javascript console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) which is available in most modern browsers or you can run javascript via the command line with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (and others).

Comment: Or jsfiddle or rhino js

Answer (score 1):

I love using http://jsfiddle.net/ .  It's my first stop when trying out new ideas in Javascript.    That being said, you could just fire up a browser and/or node.js.

The nice thing about JSFiddle is the ability to keep a library of sample code you can refer to easily from anywhere, as well as the ability to share it with others.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are asking is an online-editor where you can see the output as you change your code:

If that is so, may be use one of these:

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/

OR

Jsbin : http://jsbin.com/

OR

simply use your browsers console

this is how you open your browsers console - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

PS: JavaScript is a scripting language. it is not compiled into any other form. It simply gets interpreted and executed by the browser. :-)

Hope, this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use the node.js cli. Its a 1 click install, works on almost any system, and there are very few things you can't do in node that you can in client side.

Install http://nodejs.org/download/.

Go to command line and type node.

You are good to go.